# How should the Witch Doctor's Q ability be used?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In Heroes of the Storm, the Witch Doctor tosses pots of spiders on his Q slot.  They seem to be fairly slow and do not appear to do much damage.  I think I might be using this wrong, as I tend to throw it at enemy heroes behind the minion line.  **How should I be using this ability?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use this ability for map-specific harassment and I think that's the best way.

- Is the enemy team trying to  fight a merc camp? Throw some spiders in there for some extra damage. They won't leave the area for fear of resetting the merc camp. So your spiders will do serious damage.
- Is the enemy team trying to collect a tribute? The damage from your spiders will reset the channeling.
- Are you team fighting in a corridor? Your spiders will apply major damage as the enemies funnel into the area.

I don't tend to use spiders in lane, because of all the movement that can happen and to save mana. Simply backing up and waiting for the spiders to time out is a good way to mitigate a lot of this damage. I tend to only use the spiders in lane if I need to push the minion waves back or I need to help clear a lane.

Your zombie circle / range auto attack is the best form of wave clear.

If you are going to use this ability in lane, try to target melee heroes. The melee heroes will have to move back and therefore not be able to attack minions.

Comment: Corpse Spiders will target the closest enemy.  If you can get a good angle in a lane, aim it near the enemy hero to avoid wasting it on lane minions.

Comment: @nonterrorist Even if your spiders make the hero move away from the minions, that might be good enough. If your goal is to harass the enemy hero and push the wave and keep the enemy hero from pushing.

Comment: So rather than an attack, simply use it for, "Well you COULD go for X objective, but X is now covered in spiders.", which seems like a good idea.  Thanks!

Comment: @MadMAxJr Yeah, exactly!! Harass those objectives and delay things like recalls or merc camps. And when an enemy hero is using a channeling ability throw spiders at them for max damage :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a valid and good use, assuming the spiders actually agro to the heroes and not the minions.  The spiders are not good at lane pushing like the toads are, but they do make for good harass.  Since they cannot be targeted, you force enemy heroes to either flee or stand there and take the damage.  If you take Leaping Spiders at level 16, the spiders become a lot more useful.  You have the right idea, but make sure you use them meaningfully to harass and don't just throw them because they're off cooldown